# Understanding the difference between subject and object

Tags: language, subjectivity, explanation

Sometimes, the subject is an active thing. In the sentence, "He loves her," the subject of the sentence is active.

Other times, the subject is a passive thing. In the sentence "He is the subject of ridicule", He is a subject, but is passive. He isn't doing anything.

Why does subject have an active and passive sense?

Comment: @Formalhaut The question seems to fit better on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ Could you please move it.

Comment: It's all about _interaction_, but the roles can change. In "he loves her" and "he is loved by her", the subject is active or passive. What is interesting is that in ALL _interactions_, there is always one subject and one object, even if the subject or/and the object are collections of multiple entities: "they [subject is ONE entity (a set of things)] love the gods [object is equivalent]".

Comment: This is a grammar question, not a philosophy question.

Comment: @RodolfoAP humans aren't up to the three body problem in their interactions yet. This is why non-dyadic relationships often have difficulties.

Comment: in the sentence "He is the subject of ridicule"  (grammatically) "he" is subject and "the subject of..." is object !:)

Comment: so we can conclude, that grammatical(syntactical) subject/object relation is not identical with the "semantical"(meaning) one. (in "passive form" it is commonly reversed)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on Linguistics StackExchange. (Windy City sends its regards!)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates to grammar.

Answer (score 0):

This is better answered on linguistics, but we can provide an answer. You say:

> "He is the subject of ridicule" [is passive]

This is not true. Merely putting the word 'subject' as a predicate noun does not make a sentence passive. The [passive/active distinction](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/passive-voice/) is given in terms of verb voice. This means for the change, there must be a change in the [morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_(linguistics)) of the verb phrase. However, you also have another misunderstanding. The active/passive distinction applies to [transitive verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb) because it requires an object rather than a nominal complement like that after the [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)). Let's take a look at a typical example:

> He **threw** the ball. (active voice)
> The ball **was thrown** by him. (passive voice)

Now one with the word subject as a noun:

> The king **thanked** his subject. (active voice)
> The subject **was thanked** by the king. (passive voice)

Notice in both cases the shift in the construction of the verb which includes the addition of the [auxiliary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb)? Notice in the second example that subject is in the first example, and the voice is still active?

As mentioned by others, we have more than one 'subject' to contend with. We have the subject of the sentence, which is a grammatical category. And we have the noun phrase 'The subject' which has nothing to do with the grammatical category, but rather is just a noun. Active voice simply means that the grammatical subject is the agent or the cause of the activity in the sentence, and passive voice simply means that we move the object of the activity to the subject of the sentence to emphasize it.